# @FindBy annotation for radio buttons

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to select one of the several values of type radio button using `@FindBy`.
Here is my html code that I need to automate.

I tried giving `@FindBy(how=How.CSS,using= "[type='radio']" and value)`
But I have to pass in the value dynamically. ie. Chose BlueSkies or Pangea airlines.What is the best way to write it.Will `@FindBy` return a list of WebElements and can I work on it like that. Please help.

```
   <input type="radio" name="outFlight" value="Blue Skies Airlines$361$271$7:10"/>
</td>
<td class="data_left" align="LEFT" bgcolor="CCCCCC">
<font size="-1" face="ARIAL">
<b>Blue Skies Airlines 361</b>
</font>
</td>
<td class="data_center_mono" align="CENTER" valign="TOP" bgcolor="CCCCCC">
<font size="-1" face="ARIAL">7:10</font>
<br/>
</td>
<td class="data_center" align="CENTER" bgcolor="CCCCCC" nowrap="">
<font size="-1" face="ARIAL">non-stop</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="data_verb_xcols" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="4">
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="frame_action_xrows" rowspan="2" align="CENTER" bgcolor="#FFCC00" valign="CENTER">
<input type="radio" name="outFlight" value="Pangea Airlines$362$274$9:17"/>
</td>
<td class="data_left" align="LEFT" bgcolor="CCCCCC">
<font size="-1" face="ARIAL">
<b>Pangaea Airlines 362</b>
</font>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[type='radio']")
private List<WebElement> radioButtons;
```

Some more explanation supporting the solution give by @Guy, you can write an method to select radio dynamically. For an example

```
public void selectRadio(String airlineName){
  for(WebElement radio : radioButtons){
    if(radio.getAttribute("value").contains(airlineName)
        radio.click();
  }
}
```

You can use iterator if you wish. You just need to call this method by page object passing the airlineName as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

The value in `@FindBy` can't be dynamic. You can split it to two

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[value*='Blue Skies Airlines']")
private WebElement blueSkyesRadioButton;

@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[value*='Pangea Airlines']")
private WebElement pangeaAirlinesRadioButton;
```

Or to insert them both to list and work with indexes

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "[type='radio']")
private List<WebElement> radioButtons;
```

Comment: yes, @rajsat, you can define a custom method to return web element by providing the value from above radioButtons list.